# Guardar datos printf en una cadena - PHP

Tags: php, printf

Hola a todos tengo problemas al guardar los datos de la función **printf** en una variable.

este es mi código :

```html
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$ultima_fecha = "12/08/2018 07:16:26";
$indice1 = explode("/", $ultima_fecha);
$anio = $indice1[2];
$mes = $indice1[1];
$dia = $indice1[0];
$rest = substr($anio, 0, 4);
$hora = substr($anio, -8);
$fechaInicio = $rest . "-" . $mes . "-" . $dia . " " . $hora;
$fecha1 = new DateTime($fechaInicio);
$fecha2 = new DateTime("2019-08-20 15:52:30");
$fecha = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$formato = '%d años, %d meses, %d días, %d horas, %d minutos';
echo sprintf($formato, $fecha->y, $fecha->m, $fecha->d, $fecha->h, $fecha->i);
?>
```

El resultado del script PHP es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es que todo ese resultado se guarde en una variable como una cadena.

hay alguna forma de hacerlo ?

Comment: revisando tu codigo $anio al darle print el resultado es 2018 07:16:26?? solo tomas apartir del anio, incluyendo la hora. tienes que quitar la hora

Comment: es importante saber la hora creo que en eso no hay problema, de todos modos se le agradece por tomarse su tiempo, pero ya solucioné gracias

Answer (score 1):

Pudieras generarlo del modo siguiente

1. Declaras una variable que se llame por ejemplo `$fechaFinal` la cual vas a igualar con:

---

```
$fechaFinal = sprintf($formato, $fecha->y, $fecha->m, $fecha->d, $fecha->h, $fecha->i);
```

1. Ahora todo ese valor esta contenido en dicha variable; lo cual te permite mandarla a imprimir de este modo

---

```
echo $fechaFinal;
```

De modo que logras mantener en uso a `sprintf` y cuando imprimas el resultado, se debería ver asi:

```
1 años, 0 meses, 8 días, 8 horas, 36 minutos
```

Incluso si ocupas la función `gettype()` para saber que tipo de dato se esta almacenado, de este modo

```
echo gettype($fechaFinal);
```

El resultado en consola debería ser:

```
string
```

> Lo cual te indica claramente que se esta almacenado un valor en
>   formato de cadena de texto

Answer (score 1):

Solo necesitas asignarlo a una variable ya que el método `sprintf` regresa como resultado un `string`.

Es decir:

```
$resultado = sprintf($formato, $fecha->y, $fecha->m, $fecha->d, $fecha->h, $fecha->i);
```

La documentación oficial indica lo siguiente:

> #### `string sprintf ( string $format [, mixed $args [, mixed $... ]] )`
>
> Devuelve un string producido según el string de formateo dado por
>   **format**.

Puedes encontrar información en la documentación oficial en el ejemplo 9 y 10.

### Referencias

- [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 1):

A mi me da pena cuando veo código que no aprovecha al máximo los objetos.

En tu caso concreto, `$fecha` es un objeto completo, con métodos propios para imprimir lo que quieras y como quieras. ¿Para qué invocar otra función para hacer lo que el objeto ya puede hacer por sí solo y en una sola llamada al objeto?

> **Intentar usar `sprintf` es renunciar al método `format` que el objeto tiene como parte suya propia.**

Por ejemplo aquí manipulas el objeto cinco veces (haces cinco llamadas a cinco propiedades del objeto) y usas una función suplementaria:

```
sprintf($formato, $fecha->y, $fecha->m, $fecha->d, $fecha->h, $fecha->i);
```

Con este código, obtienes el mismo resultado, manipulando el objeto una sola vez y sin tener que acudir a otra función suplementaria:

```
$str=$fecha->format("%y años, %m meses, %d días, %h horas, %i minutos");
```

Ya tienes todo lo que quieres, está en la variable `$str`.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente hay forma, una de ellas es usando **ob_get_contents** para capturar lo que tiene de tu **echo**.

> **ob_start** 
>   Esto activará el buffer de salida impidiendo que se imprima el script
>
> **ob_get_contents** 
>   Devolverá el contenido del buffer de salida.
>
> **ob_end_clean()** 
>   Removerá el contenido del búfer de salida y inactivarlo

Principalmente tiene utilidad para capturar los valores de funciones que devuelven datos con impresión y no con variables

```php
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$ultima_fecha = "12/08/2018 07:16:26";
$indice1 = explode("/", $ultima_fecha);
$anio = $indice1[2];
$mes = $indice1[1];
$dia = $indice1[0];
$rest = substr($anio, 0, 4);
$hora = substr($anio, -8);
$fechaInicio = $rest . "-" . $mes . "-" . $dia . " " . $hora;
$fecha1 = new DateTime($fechaInicio);
$fecha2 = new DateTime("2019-08-20 15:52:30");
$fecha = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$formato = '%d años, %d meses, %d días, %d horas, %d minutos';

ob_start(); //Activa el buffer de salida basicamente

// todo el codigo que quieres que sea capturado
echo sprintf($formato, $fecha->y, $fecha->m, $fecha->d, $fecha->h, $fecha->i);

// obtiene el buffer de salida y lo asigna en una variable
$data = ob_get_contents();

//finaliza el buffer de salida
ob_end_clean();

//un simple var dump para saber que hay en data
var_dump($data);

?>
```